# Associate Azure WebJobs in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure-webjobs

In the [Windows Azure build keynote (2014-04-03)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/KEY02) they demo Azure WebJobs. You can clearly see how they associate the current WebJob with the ASP.Net website application. However, I don't have this option available in Visual Studio 2013. Does it come with the new [Web Features in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc.aspx)? I haven't installed it (still RC...) but it's clearly not in the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes). I've installed the latest Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.3.

In the video you can see the association in action:
[image: build azure day 2 keynote]

**Update:**
After installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC I still don't see the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this awesome extension that I was looking for:

> With this extension you can right click on a web project in Visual Studio and associate a console project as a WebJob. After doing that when you publish the web project the webjob project will be published into the correct location in your Azure Web Site

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4824551-2660-4afa-aba1-1fcc1673c3d0